# (Generic) Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am trying to build a WebAPI (with consuming client app) that can authenticate with azure active directory, but doesn't rely entirely on Active Directory.

I have a version working nicely, which uses...

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

...but I am concerned this, therefore, isn't the "pure" way of doing it.

For example...

> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/

... uses the Microsoft identity platform. Writing this into code feels like getting an Azure AD tattoo and I would like to write something "more generic". Who knows, one day, we might choose a different means of authenticating our users.

Can anyone please advise what I should be reading up on to achieve this? There is plenty of documentation out there, but most of it says "put A into B" and "put C into D" but doesn't expand much on what's actually going on.

Comment: An API doesn't have to use any MS libraries. The tokens are JSON Web Tokens, and you can use any JWT library to validate them. The library usually only needs to know the *authority* and the *valid audiences*. From the authority it can download a metadata document, which will allow it to get the valid issuer, valid signing keys etc. With all that info it should be able to validate the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure this has an answer.

This is the code I used to create a generic authentication method that works with Azure AD...

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.MetadataAddress = String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration", Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]);
    o.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
});
```